# To which app engine is my domain pointing?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have several app engines running at several appspot.com's.  I don't remember which appspot that game.villagethegame.com is pointing to. How do I figure it out without going through every single app engine settings page?

Comment: Go to your DNS supplier and check the DNS records for the domain...?

Comment: I gave finding a utility and just guessed thru the list until I found the answer.